# How to create and interact with a custom grid like sudoku of size m*n in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I started working on an android project which looks something like the image attached below.[image]

I created a relative layout which should now contain two layouts. A linear which has a timer and a custom layout which should have a n*n grid layout.(say 8*10) horizontal layout.

I need to interact with grids like clicking on the grid should add an image to the grid etc. Is there a better way of implementing this rather than gridview?

Thanks

Comment: I think RecyclerView is a much more flexible and efficient way to produce grids.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) but I think GridView is better for this amount of fields.

Comment: Do GridView have capability to handle each grid